# Type error on Login using the 'login()' function

Tags: python, django

Here is the Code, I just write it as usual. And I never got this error before. The error says :
TypeError at /accounts/login/
**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given.
Exception Value : **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given.
Exception Location:     C:\Dev\Django\MyRecipe\accounts\views.py in post, line 26.

Here is the link :
https://hastebin.com/judivetasa.rb

## error at

login(self.request, user)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code.
you have a class with `login` name(`class login(View)`), also you have imported

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

These two have a conflict with each other, change your class name to `Login`(capital `L`) or something else to not override the `django` login.